# Need help Bevel and Emboss settings for my project involving metal textures

Tags: photoshop-effects, metallic, bevel

What bevel and Emboss settings do I have to change to make the metal wings in the first image look like the wings in the second image.

**First Image**
[image]

**Second Image**
[image]

Comment: With bevel/emboss [& many other aspects] the first thing you need is for the original & the copy to be the same size/resolution. Without the pixel dimensions matching, no specific 'numbers' will work. Your 2nd image is a tiny fraction of the resolution of the first, even if the screenshots uploaded are similar.

Answer (score 2):

Making a high resolution version of an existing image can be difficult because one must guess right or know how to make right looking details which actually exist only in watcher's imagination when the low resolution version is the only available one.

If Bevel&Emboss wasn't wanted I would try to paint the wanted forms in Illustrator by drawing blurred or gradient curves to make the shading. Or to make a blade in a 3D program.

Bevel&Emboss in smooth mode can produce sharp edges if one uses his own bevel curve which contains corner points and sharp steps. Such nonlinearity is rarely used because finding good settings is difficult. A small curve change causes easily a big change to the result, so it's virtually impossible to predict what's needed. The right curve + other settings (if they exist) can be found accidentally. Otherwise you would already have something useful shown by experienced longtime members of this site.

Here's my attempt. It's not perfect, but it shows that the middle ridge on the blade is possible.

[image]

It was originally a light grey filled area. The bevel curve got some corner points which were dragged here and there. Suddenly the shown effect appeared.

The other effect settings were adjusted at first so that the blade area got a symmetric looking gradient. It made possible to try, if discontinuous mapping would make a right looking sharp ridge in the middle. The next image shows the same effect before trying to insert corners and steps to the curve:

[image]